# standard way to tag/annotate code that can be optimized?

Tags: java, optimization, annotations

I am looking for a way to mark somehow the code that can be optimized, so that me or anyone who comes after me on the project, knows what and how can be optimized when performance becomes a challenge.

Reason why I don't optimize at the moment is that code clarity is most of the times more important than code optimization, based on my and many other's experience (e.g. check "Effective Java Programming" of Joshua Block). Thus I prefer to keep code clear and easy to understand (which basically means, implement things the way anyone would do it, try no fancy stuff until really needed). Though, when performance becomes an issue, it is good to know exactly where to look into and do the optimizations at the cost of loosing from code clarity.
I would like to be able to mark the places where code can be optimized and give some hints on how though.

The way I was thinking to do so is by using an annotation like:

```
public class UserDao {
    @Optimizable (hint="cache returned data; ")
    public List<User> getUsers(int userType) {
        //some code getting user and checking if user is of that type.
    }
}
```

Is there a standard - community wide used - way to mark your code for such? Or do you have a better idea of how to do it?

Using annotation makes it easy for tools to check for optimizable code and generate some reports for that. Another way might be to use a javadoc like tag, but not sure how easy a tool might be able to discover that.

Thanks,
Stef.

#### ADDED:

Ok, seems that Rick's answer covers all ways of doing this in comments.
How about annotations though? I find this to have some advantages as you can discover code issues/optimization options even if you don't have source code and optimize by offering a new implementation for those methods/classes and take advantage of polymorphism. Do you know if there are any standard annotations for such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know about three standard tags in comments:

- TODO : non-critical issue for next release; used for optimizations
- XXX : critical issue, but code is working; needs to be looked at before next release
- FIXME : critical issue, non-working code; this marks real bugs

TODO and FIXME are well known and discussed above.

XXX is typically used for sections which are working in the current state, but need to be removed. These are typically ugly hacks to fix a bug in short period, strongly coupled code which assumes strong environmental conditions which might change and code which is known to work, but assumed to be unstable.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I've added a comment to the end of my question. I would be interested if anyone is using annotations for this as to me they seem to give a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 6):

Yes: Use `// TODO: Some comment`

Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans all recognise this and create a "todo" list for you. Many code quality plugins and CI servers e.g. [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (previously Hudson) also recognise this and can create "technical debt" reports and progress graphs etc.

Make sure you use that exact syntax: `// TODO:`

Comment: +1 IntelliJ also creates todo lists for you and I think all IDEs color-code TODO comments to stand out.

Comment: `FIXME` is fairly standard as well. If an IDE doesn't recognize these, you can always grep...

Comment: Some code review systems and CI systems (Hudson does) will isolate these for you as well, and give you a report of how many "TODOs" and "FIXMEs" various classes have as part of a code quality/improvement report.

Comment: thanks Bohemian. That is a bit different. I'm already using todo (in IntelliJ) for general stuff, like things not yet implemented migration to some package etc. But I would like to have some specific items for optimizations only. FIXME seems to be closer to what I need, but still not very accurate as an optimization is not really a fix (code is already good ... whereas not the best optimized).

Comment: The idea of using an annotation came from the book Concurrency in Practice, where they have the annotations ThreadSafe and NotThreadSafe (http://jcip.net/annotations/doc/index.html). Not sure though if that's the best way to do it. I guess using  '//todo:optimization:some details' might also work. And then doing a grep in the sources for that.

Comment: Actually, annotation might be still better, as this way, if you don't have the sources, you can still get an idea of where you can optimize the code. Thus you could extend the classes, or offer new implementation for interface using the optimization hint. So you can optimize by extension rather than by modifying the existing code.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but just for future reference: there is a @Debt annotation which can be used to indicate there is some code which is in need of refactoring / updating / fixing. See: http://kenai.com/projects/csdutilities/pages/Debt for more info. There is also integration with Maven available to provide you with some more info and possibly make the build fail if there are to many @Debt annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of such a tag. You can make something up so long as you use it consistently throughout your code.

I can see the value of such a tag. Often naïve, slow code is preferable to complex, fast code as it is faster to write and more likely to be free of bugs. When the customer complains about speed, you want to revisit the naïve, slow bits and searching for pre-written comments makes this easier.

Here are some ideas:

```
// OPT: Here is a potential optimization; it's ambiguous with "optional".
// OPTIMIZATION: a long tag.
// LHF: Low hanging fruit. Not intuitive, but the acronym is cool.
// FASTER: This is a real word, six letters long.
// BOOST: Another real word, five letters.
```

I think I prefer the first one, `// OPT:`.

e.g.

```
// OPT: This report can be re-written with PL/SQL, but 
// you'll need to use JDBC rather than Hibernate.
```

or

```
// OPT: Adding a bloom filter in front of this structure will half
// the number of disk accesses.
```